# How do I change the output of Matlab when using inverse Laplace?

Tags: matlab, inverse-laplace

Here is my input:

```
syms s 
F = (2+2*s*(exp(-s))+4*(exp(-2*s)))/(s^2)*(s^2+2*s+10); 
ilaplace(F)
```

An the output is :

```
20*t + 4*dirac(t - 1) + 4*dirac(t - 2) + 20*heaviside(t - 1) + 8*heaviside(t - 2) + 2*dirac(t) + 2*dirac(1, t - 1) + 40*heaviside(t - 2)*(t - 2) + 4`
```

Can I change it to see it in terms of cos and sin?

Edit: I have changed my input to

```
s/(s^4 + 2*s^3 + 10*s^2)
```

The new output is:

```
1/10 - (exp(-t)*(cos(3*t) + sin(3*t)/3))/10
```

Unfortunately, I still haven't found a way to do the entire function at once without removing the "exp".

Comment: Have you attempted to use `simplify()` ?

Comment: I just did. Nothing changes.

Comment: Sorry, but I failed to understand what do you want to get as a result?